# PyGILState_STATE didn't change after PyGILState_Ensure()/PyGILState_Release()

Tags: c, python-2.7, python-c-api

I have a shared library written in C and called in Python.

In a pthread, some Python C API called between PyGILState_Ensure() and PyGILState_Release().

The value of PyGILState_STATE remains the same all the time.

**c code**

```c
PyGILState_STATE st = PyGILState_Ensure()
printf("After Ensure, PyGILState_STATE == %d\n", st);
// Python C API call
PyGILState_Release(st);
printf("After Release, PyGILState_STATE == %d\n", st);
```

**output**

```sh
After Ensure, PyGILState_STATE == 1
After Release, PyGILState_STATE == 1
```

According to its definition, 1 means PyGILState_UNLOCKED.

```c
typedef
    enum {PyGILState_LOCKED, PyGILState_UNLOCKED}
        PyGILState_STATE;
```

Why didn't the state change ?

Comment: You're printing the local variable, not the real GIL

Comment: PyGILState_Ensure()/PyGILState_Release() call on st will not change it?

Comment: You need to reread the docs; the functions don't do what you think they do. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyGILState_Ensure